# XmlInclude All Derived Similarly To Knowtypes Solution in WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, serialization

I have a service method returning `BaseModel`, which has many derived classes. I wanted my service to be able to get the requested item which i.e. resolves to `DerivedClass1 : BaseModel` and return it. Of course the return type of my service would be `BaseModel`.

In this case I had to add to my BaseModel definition `DerivedClass1` as a `KnownType`

```
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass1))]
[DataContract]
public class BaseModel {
   ...
```

The list of derived classes is changing and I don't want to always update this, so I found a solution where I can do this:

```
[KnownType("DerivedTypes")]
[Serializable]
public class BaseModel {
  ...
  private static Type[] DerivedTypes() {
        return (from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() where t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseModel)) select t).ToArray();
  }
  ...
```

So now every derived class is listed as `KnownType`. Great!
Now I would need the same for the needed `XmlInclude` too. I am using

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedClass1))]
```

annotation. Is there a way to do something similar? Is there a better way to do this? Could it be done somehow like

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude("DerivedTypes")]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `XmlSerializer` you can pass a list of types to its constructor.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseModel), BaseModel.DerivedTypes());
```